# Codeigniter PHP Object not found, The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello i'm kinda new in php frameworks especilly in codeigniter..

this is my view

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title> Login </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url(); ?>/public/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url(); ?>/public/css/styles.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url(); ?>/public/css/login.css"/>

    <script src="<?=base_url()?>/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url()?>/public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url()?>/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--login modal-->
<div id="loginModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <img class="lmsImg" src="<?=base_url(); ?>/public/img/books.png"/>
                <h1 class="text-center">Library Management System </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>homepage/loadhomeView"> Sign In </a> </button>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is my controller

```
Class Homepage extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }


    function loadhomeView() {
        $this->load->view('homeView.php');
    }
}
```

my problem here is that when i try to load the homepage/loadhomeView it prompts me that it is not found wherein i have the .php file in my controller folder and the homeView.php file in my view folder.. could you kindly help me in my problem.

here is my config setup

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/LibrarySystem';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$route['default_controller'] = "login/loadLogin";
```

Comment: Are you done with Removing the index.php file. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Does this http://localhost/LibrarySystem/index.php/homepage/loadhomeView work ?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Islam oh yes sir that works. but why is it that when i remove the index.php in the url it does not work?

Comment: search at SO or google with `how to remove index.php from codeigniter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks like it should work so I would do the following.  Try navigating to

`http://localhost/LibrarySystem/homepage/loadhomeView`

or

`http://localhost/LibrarySystem/index.php/homepage/loadhomeView`

and see if either of those work.  If the later works you can remove the index.php using a `.htaccess` file.

One thing I spotted was that in your view you have the following

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>homepage/loadhomeView">
```

However you're you don't add a `/` at the end of your base URL where you define it in the config file so it should be

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/homepage/loadhomeView">
```

Comment: hello sir. i tried navigating to http://localhost/LibrarySystem/homepage/loadhomeView but it still object not found